# How do I access classes compiled in Gradle buildSrc from the project build.gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm new to Gradle. I've read that code in buildSrc is compiled by Gradle and added to the classpath of the project's build.gradle. What I can't figure out is how to create an instance of classes in buildSrc from build.gradle.

Here is my directory structure:

```
build.gradle
src/test/groovy
    com.company.content.acceptance 
    com.company.tests.acceptance   
buildSrc/src/test/groovy
    com.company.test.report
```

How can I create an instance of a class in package com.company.test.report within the project build.gradle?

Thanks,

-erzsebet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes in `buildSrc/src/test/groovy` can't be accessed from the main build, but classes in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy` can.